# JMeter call to kerberos protected rest api fails (works from IE browser)

Tags: rest, jmeter, kerberos

Using JMeter to execute get request on a rest api that is protected with Kerberos (active directory).   API works from Internet Explorer, fails from Chrome and fails from JMeter.

The first request gets a 401 response (expected this)

Here is the second request.  It looks like it has a Kerberos authentication token:

Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Authorization: Negotiate YIIFwwYGK (...I CUT THIS SHORT)

Response:
HEADER:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 01 Mar 2019 20:52:42 GMT
Content-Length: 3231

BEGINNING OF BODY:
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.WebException","StackTrace":"   at

Does anyone have ideas of how to make this request work in JMeter?

Are there client settings or server settings that can be set to make the rest api work from chrome or JMeter?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at HTTPCLIENT-1625, I'd recommend using Fiddler as a proxy for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to your Test Plan and configure it to use your domain credentials, also specify [Domain and Realm](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2015/10/21/domain-to-kerberos-realm-mapping/).

Additionally you will need to amend [`krb5.conf`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1/bin/krb5.conf) and in some cases [`jaas.conf`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1/bin/jaas.conf) files to match your infrastructure setup.

Check out [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article to learn how to bypass Kerberos login challenge in JMeter tests.